# Import data from Excel to SQL Server using T-Sql

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an excel sheet . having different data column 
One column having data like

```
Effiency
=======
70%
80%
50%
```

Column format is `[<0]"";0%`

when I importing data from excel to sql server this column shows blank values in sql server
I am using

```
SELECT Effiency 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'Excel 12.0;Database=E:\BI\Excel_Source_File\CS_Source_File\Camp201201231.xlsx',
   'SELECT * FROM [Detailed_report$B7:AP39]'
)
```

I also use option IMEX=1 same prob.

Comment: Why dont use SQL management studios Import utility?

Comment: The scenario is that I need to get data from different sheet locations its a unstructured format sheet. my client download this sheet in a location they are around 100 sheets per day.